# How to avoid calling a function twice in (recur ..)

Tags: loops, clojure, tail-recursion

Please consider this block of code.

```
(loop [k from res '()]
    (if (< (count res) n)
      (recur (next-num k)  (conj res (next-num k)))
      (sort res)))
```

Now, suppose the function, `(next-num k)`, does some expensive computation. We can't afford to call that twice. What will be the alternative? I'm new to Clojure, and don't know many basic features. But I'm sure there must be a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `let`:

```
(loop [k from res '()]
    (if (< (count res) n)
      (let [the-next-num (next-num k)]
          (recur the-next-num  (conj res the-next-num)))
      (sort res)))
```

Comment: Or, avoid a loop entirely: `(->>
  (iterate next-num from)
  rest
  (take n)
  sort)`

Comment: @Beyamor: Your suggestion is working like charm. But I have no idea why. Would you please care to elaborate, probably in a separate answer of yours.

Comment: I undeleted my answer and explained the loopless code, but @Nathan definitely beat me to the punch on using `let`.

Answer (score 5):

Like @NathanDavis said, [`let`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let) allows you to name intermediate values:

```
(loop [k from res '()]
  (if (< (count res) n)
    (let [next-k (next-num k)]
      (recur next-k (conj res next-k)))
    (sort res)))
```

However, before reaching for a `loop`, it's worth seeing if you can compose core functions to the same effect. Often, you can write something less complex and expose the important details.

The meat of the code concerns building up a sequence of repeated applications of `next-num`. Luckily enough, there's a core function that does this: [`iterate`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate). Using `iterate`, we can create an infinite lazy sequence of values:

```
(iterate next-num from)
; => (from, from', from'', ...)
```

However, we don't want the first of these values. We can obtain the rest of the sequence with, well, [`rest`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rest):

```
(rest
  (iterate next-num from))
; => (from', from'', from''', ...)
```

At this point, we can grab `n` values with [`take`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/take):

```
(take n
  (rest
    (iterate next-num from)))
; => (from', from'', from''')
```

And finally, we can sort these `n` values:

```
(sort
  (take n
    (rest
      (iterate next-num from))))
 ; => (from'', from', from''')
```

Of course, deeply nesting function calls soon becomes awkward. The threading macro [`->>`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) (like its brother [`->`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E)) is a bit of syntactic sugar that lets us rearrange our code into something a little nicer:

```
(->>
  (iterate next-num from)
  rest
  (take n)
  sort)
```

So, you can see how a powerful library of sequence-manipulating functions lets us move away from low-level looping.

Comment: An awesome explanation, indeed. Although, I have accepted the other  answer, since `let` is, actually and precisely, the answer of my question. But this approach is definitely and unequivocally better.